# Entity Framework Foreign Key Issue

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, primary-key

I am getting a very frustrating issue:

> System.Data.UpdateException was unhandled by user code 
>   Message="Entities in 'MyProjectEntities.GroupingData' participate in the 'FK_GroupingData_AuditTrail' relationship. 
>  
>   0 related 'AuditTrail' were found. 1 'AuditTrail' is expected."

This happens when I try to add an object to the database in the GroupingData table.
Every other table where I do inserts it's fine.

Furthermore, my EDMX properly reflects my database. 
I am dumbfounded. 
If any one has faced a similar situation in the past, I would like some advice.

Comment: Try doing db.SubmitChanges() before you insert the GroupingData-item.

Comment: Do you mean <currentContext>.SaveChanges() ? I'm trying it now.

Comment: Doesn't seem to resolve the issue -- grrr.

Comment: can you post your db schema and edmx? (at least the relevant parts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the relationship MyProjectEntities.GroupingData -> AuditTrail to 0..1 - * perhaps?